# ROCAUC legend and x/y-axis font size using Yellowbrick

Tags: python, plot, font-size, roc, yellowbrick

I am using Yellowbrick ROCAUC. The plot font size (legend and x/y axis) is **very small**. Is there a way to increase the **font size** of the ROCAUC plot?

```
model = clf
visualizer = ROCAUC(model) 
visualizer.fit(X_train, y_train)        
visualizer.score(X_test, y_test)       
visualizer.show()
```

I tried the below for loop before the show(), but it is not working on the axis and legend font size, and did not find in the documentation:

```
for label in visualizer.ax.texts:
    label.set_size(12)
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter the same problem.
I've found this loop useful:

```
for xtick,ytick in zip(visualizer.ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks(),visualizer.ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()):
    xtick.label.set_fontsize(12) 
    ytick.label.set_fontsize(12)
```